# Predefining $_GET parameter on open of index.php

Tags: php

Is there a way to set a $_GET parameter with certain value on open of "index.php"

For example:      the url being = ".../index.php?somePara=value"

I tried using :

```
header("Location: index.php?page=1");
 exit();
```

But I get an error of

> "localhost redirected you too many times."

Edit:
Thanks, Qirel, that works, I need it because i have variables that are attached to $_GET parameter, so instead of setting them to NULL and then passing value to them after a if($_GET) check -> so that they wont get an error of undefined, I was wondering how pass value on open of the file.

Comment: `if (empty($_GET['page'])) { header(..); exit; }`, although it seems rather pointless, why would you need this? If you need that parameter, just assign it to a variable if there is no value in the GET array

Comment: remove white spaces

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. The issue is not to "set" such a value/parameter/argument. The questions is _when_ and _where_ you want to set it. Please add details to your question. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it._

Comment: Thanks that works, I need it because i have variables that are attached to $_GET parameter,  so instead of setting them to NULL and then passing value to them after a if($_GET) check -> so that they wont get an error of undefined, I was wondering how pass value on open of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is either that you do not have a condition, or you have, but it is always true in this use-case.

Your question mentions the condition:

> Is there a way to set a $_GET parameter with certain value on open of
>   "index.php"

but your code does not contain that:

```
header("Location: index.php?page=1");
 exit();
```

So you can wrap this into a condition:

```
if (isset($_GET["certain"]) && ($_GET["certain"] === "value")) {
    header("Location: index.php?page=1");
    exit();
}
```

Note that the string parameter of `header` does not contain `certain`, since that would result in an infinite loop. You can also check in the `if` whether there is a `page` parameter if you intend to include `certain` there.

I have read the comment which suggested to set the corresponding key of `$_GET` to the expected value instead of a redirect, but that is not always an option, since you might want to beautify a URL or even to redirect to another site's page.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_GET` parameters are used in my code, I always set a default value for these variables since you are never sure if it is set.

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Guest';

// This is the shorter version for
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
} else {
    $name = 'Guest';
}
```

Your method of solving your problem will get you into an infinite loop. You could however do:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?page=1");
    exit;
}
```